# Is combining std::execution and OpenMP advisable?

Tags: c++, openmp, c++17

I use OpenMP since some time now. Recently, on a new project, I choose to use c++17, for some features.

Because of that, I have been concerned by std::execution which allow to parallelize algorithms. That seems really powerful and elegant, But their are a lot of feature of OpenMP really useful that are not easy to use with algorithms (barrier, SIMD, critical, etc..).

So I think to mix the `std::execution::par` (or `unseq_par`) with OpenMP. Is it a good idea, or should i stay only with OpenMP?

Comment: Stay with OpenMP, don't mix the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is **not officially supported**. It may or may not work, depending on the implementation, but it is not portable.

Only the most recent version, OpenMP 5.0, even defines the interaction with C++11. In general, using anything from C++11 and forward *"may result in unspecified behavior"*. While future versions of the OpenMP specification are expected to address the following features, currently their use may result in unspecified behavior.

- Alignment support
- Standard layout types
- Allowing move constructs to throw
- Defining move special member functions
- **Concurrency**
- **Data-dependency ordering: atomics and memory model**
- **Additions to the standard library**
- Thread-local storage
- Dynamic initialization and destruction with concurrency
- **C++11 library**

While C++17 and its specific high-level parallelism support is not mentioned, it is clear from this list, that it is unsupported.